# Is there a way to download individual .apk packages from Alpine repos?

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

I need to install a couple of packages on a device that does not have internet access.

The idea was to download packages, transfer them to the device and then install using `apk add --allow-untrusted <name>`. Perhaps it was too logical because I cannot figure out how to download these apks from sites such as `pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages`. I can see what's in the package, but that's about it. Does anyone know why?

Also, if anyone knows a place I can download them from, please, tell me... Thanks!

Comment: Link: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/. Replace `x86_64` with your PC's cpu  architecture.

Answer (score 9):

For example for `curl`, try

```
apk update
apk fetch curl
apk add ./curl-7.61.1-r1.apk
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a mirror list of servers, where you can download from:
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/MIRRORS.txt

Packages can be downloaded from e.g.:
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/x86_64/

Comment: Thanks! I can also browse the version in https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/, this helps me, yesterday update cause libssl broken, and broke apk tools, I can't even install anything. I need to download the https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/libssl3-3.0.9-r1.apk, extract using 7zip (I'm in WSL2), copy paste the file to the /lib/libssl.so.3, and retry... and it works... The maintainer doesn't even give a news if the package failed :/